# "Function argument" formatting in theme not recognized by RStudio

Tags: themes, rstudio

I downloaded the [Antigua theme](https://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/#!/editor/theme/Antigua) and added it to RStudio. Many of the formatting scopes seen on the website are implemented in RStudio, but not all of them. In particular, the "Function argument" scope is not implemented. See how it appears on the website
[image]
vs. how it appears on my computer
[image]

From this description of [themes in RStudio](https://rstudio.github.io/rstudio-extensions/rstudio-theme-creation.html), I get the feeling "Function argument" is not a valid scope in RStudio. Is that accurate? Is the formatting for R in the themes website a bug?

Comment: I had the same problem, and am equally mystified. Would be great to resolve this.

Comment: I have the same question. I am using the Monakai theme. The theme looks different in RStudio from in SublimeText. It's very confusing. It would be great if someone can have this resolved.